# Is str_replace done when there is an Array in the Array?

Tags: php, arrays, str-replace

```
$blocked_list   = array(';', '/*','---','*','\*','\'','select','union','join','where','insert','like','drop','and','have','alter','0x','"','\'','location','LOCATİON','LOCATION','refresh','script','frame','iframe','İFRAME','IFRAME','\\n');

$check_array = [
                [
                    'key' => 'select',
                    'lang' => [
                        'en' => 'Select',
                        'tr' => 'Sec'
                    ]
                ]
            ];
$new_tk     = str_ireplace($blocked_list, '', $check_array);
```

It gives me the following error as a result.

"**Warning:**  Array to string conversion in /var/www/...."
How can I str_replace the array inside the array as in the $array_check variable?

Comment: You either need to iterate through the array and apply the replcement function to each string separately or you need a function doing exactly that for you... Take a look at the recursive version of array_walk: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php

Comment: Incidentally, if you are expecting this code to provide you some kind of security, you are dangerously wrong. Please read up on how to properly escape text for a particular output context (a string that is safe for HTML looks different from a string that is safe for JavaScript or SQL, and none of them can be created with a replacement list like this), and how to write parametrised SQL queries which separate data from code. All you will achieve with this code, if you get it working, is some very mangled text.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will work on array_walk. I would appreciate if you could give information about what I can do for a safer transaction.

Comment: I'm not convinced that your task is a task that should be done, but you need to offer a flat array to `str_replace()`.  You will need to determine in advance which language you are replacing for, then only accommodate that single language for replacements.  As IMSoP has said, this is probably not a good idea to implement.